# Multiple parallel request is not handled by server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the progress of a controller method. I have used `setInterval` method to call the progress method inside the controller but the ajax call inside the `setInterval` only hits the controller after the execution of controller method and till that time the ajax requests status keeps `pending` on browser network tab.

I have considered making first method asynchronous

Java Script code

```
function Import() {
    $('.loader').show();

    var checked;
    if ($('#chkNewCycle').is(":checked")) {
        checked = 'on';
    }
    else {
        checked = 'off';
    }

    var NewCycle = { IsNewCycle: checked };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/DataImport/Import',
        type: 'POST',
        data: NewCycle,
        success: function (result) {
            $('.loader').hide();
            if (result == "success") {
                window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                alert("Imported file for processing.");
                ClearData();

            }
            else {
                alert(result);
            }
        }
    });   


    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        $.getJSON('/DataImport/GetProgress', function (json) {
            console.log(json.Progress);
            $('#progress').html(json.Progress + '%');
        });
    }, 2000);



}
```

controller.cs

```
public async Task<string> Import(string IsNewCycle)
{
/*Some Code*/

await Task.Run(() => { 
/*Some Code*/

int iProgress =Convert.ToInt32(dProgress * 100);
HttpContext.Application["Progress" ] = iProgress;

 });

return string;


}

public ActionResult GetProgress()
{
return Json(new
{
     Progress = HttpContext.Application["Progress"]
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need to get both the controller method hit simultaneously

Comment: I think this should work! How are you determining that it is not hitting both simultaneously

Comment: Inside Chrome Network tab multiple progress request status is pending

Comment: are you holding the debugger at your server side?

Comment: yes and its not hitting. It will hit once the first ajax call gets completed

Comment: if you'll hold the debugger it won't hit another. Try using log of manipulating some data. and see if changed?

Comment: `console.log(json.Progress);` I've tried consoling the result but it won't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your controller with `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute, then you can execute requests in parallel.